# Apply 'for' loop by words

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have the following .txt file:

[a.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iMDX0yimbAs3l5LsliP9TllqQpqajWOm/view?usp=sharing)

which shows the following 2 lines of data:

```
300 100 500 250 150
34984 29220 43640 36410 7980
```

I need to create a code that creates a dictionary that shows the following result:

```
A   300
B   100
C   500
D   250
E   150
```

I have tried with this code, but I cannot separate the figures, nor choose only the first line. Any ideas?

```
f.read
import string
mayusculas = string.ascii_uppercase
f = open("a.txt", "r")
for i, c in zip(mayusculas, f):
     print(i, c)
f.close()
```

[image]

**Thank you all.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes on your code:
1. Always open files using a context manager
2. You need can read the file one line at a time
3. Use `split` to break the line, don't feed it any arguments so it can parse tabs and multiple spaces properly.
Putting it all together, your code should look like this:

```
import string
mayusculas = string.ascii_uppercase
with open("clientes_pibpc.txt", "r") as f:
    for i, c in zip(mayusculas, f.readline().split()):
        print(i, c)
```

Answer (score 2):

Preserving your code structure, `split()` is what you're looking for:

```
f = '''300 100 500 250 150
34984 29220 43640 36410 7980'''    

for i, c in zip(mayusculas, (f.split('\n')[0]).split(' ')):
         print(i, c)
```

### Explanation:

`f.split('\n')`: splits your string into a list, by newline, so you get a two element list

`(f.split('\n')[0]).split(' ')`: I take the first element in your list and I split those by space, getting a five element list with the five elements you need, as stated in your example.

### Output:

```
A 300
B 100
C 500
D 250
E 150
```

Comment: This has two problems, 1. when the file is large it reads all of it, then splits it by new line and picks the first line which is a waste of resources. 2. won't work if the file tab separated or has multiple spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the first line of the file and then split it, followed by zipping with the uppercase:

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readline().split()
    final_dict = dict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase, data))
final_dict
{'A': '300', 'B': '100', 'C': '500', 'D': '250', 'E': '150'}
```